# re + What the Sorting Hat does

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Use the titles to complete the following sentence:

> I'd rather say that the + what a door that's open is usually made of is `???`

Options:

1. Half full
2. Worth more than a dime
3. Comes around
4. Loves me to death
5. 5 and seven thirds

Comment: I really like the idea and wordplay here - however, I think the display and construction could use some work - and I imagine this is why someone downvoted. You could make this a really nice puzzle by adding some flavour text or background context - as it is right now its sort of the bare minimum - more of a skeleton of a good puzzle.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil thanks for the tip. I guess I could have added a bit more text but it seems unhelpful and I think there's all the hints I could give. A matter of taste I suppose

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil also I think people down vote because it seems like it's written in broken English, but I can't fix it without ruining the puzzle

Comment: I can attempt to try and fix the grammar without ruining the puzzle if you want?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil sure, go ahead :)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil the title "what the sorting hat does" -> "placement" so "use the titles" -> "use placements" so I returned the s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd rather say

> 1. Half full

What a door that's open is

> Ajar, and this is usually made of glass. You'd rather be an optimist and say "The glass is half full than half empty".

The title

> A silver lining - since you are an optimist. I hope!

Comment: oh right - a jar

Comment: @Tom try again with the title

Comment: @Dotan, thanks for the prompt - hope better now, nice wordplay as BG says!

Comment: @Tom It's a little embarrassing, I was referring to a 'place mat', but I thought it was called a 'placement' which is also the thing you need to do to solve the puzzle. I changed the title now.

Comment: @Doran - intriguing, this is a three pipe problem, I will keep thinking. Also anyone with ideas is  welcome to post. Maybe above has just scratched the surface.

Answer (score 2):

the title:

> What the Sorting Hat does => **Placement** (harry potter). 
>  re+placement = replacement. This is how you solve the puzzle.

The instructions:

> Use **the title**-s to complete the following sentence: 
>  Placement: 
>  Use **What the Sorting Hat does**-s to complete the following sentence: 
>  Use **replacement**-s to complete the following sentence: 
>  Use replacements to complete the following sentence:

The sentence:

> I'd rather say that the + what **a door that's open** is usually made of is ??? 
>  I'd rather say that the + what **a jar**, is usually made of is ??? 
>  I'd rather say that the +  **what a jar is usually made of** is ??? 
>  I'd rather say that the **glass** is ??? 
>  half full

Comment: Unfortunately, in English the words "placement" and "replacement" are not synonyms, and the mechanic of this puzzle is definitely *replacement* rather than *placement*.

Comment: you could put it as "Re: What the Sorting Hat does"

Comment: @mr23ceec This question has more problems than words. Thanks :)